# Four-tuple distance to zero issue

Tags: java, arrays, math, tuples

I am working on a project in school that requires us to develop a program to calculate the distance of a four-tuple of non-negative integers to zero.

The description reads "Suppose that you start with a four-tuple of nonnegative integers (a,b,c,d) and that you repeatedly apply this rule:
(a,b,c,d) → (|a−b|,|b−c|,|c−d|,|d−a|)
That is, you replace a by |a−b|, b by |b−c|, c by |c−d|, and d by |d−a|.
It turns out that, eventually, you will obtain the four-tuple (0,0,0,0). For example, starting with (7, 3, 6, 1) and applying the above rule repeatedly, we get 
(7,3,6,1) → (4,3,5,6) → (1,2,1,2) → (1,1,1,1) → (0,0,0,0) 
In this case, it took four applications of the rule to transform (7, 3, 6, 1) into (0, 0, 0, 0), so we say that its distance to zero is four."

What I got so far is:

```
int [] array = new int []{a, b, c, d};
    int counter = 0;

    while (array[0] != 0 && array[1] != 0 && array[2] != 0 && array[3] != 0){

        array[0] = (int) Math.abs(array[0]-array[1]);

        array[1] = (int) Math.abs(array[1]-array[2]);

        array[2] = (int) Math.abs(array[2]-array[3]);

        array[3] = (int) Math.abs(array[3]-array[0]);
        counter++;
    }
```

However, it does not print out what I need it to and do not know where to go from there, any help?

example: when a, b, c, and d are set as 7, 3, 6 and 1, it prints it out as (1,0,0,1) instead of (0,0,0,0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you reassign `array[0]` to a new value which is then used in `array[3]`, although you want to use the "old" one. You should use an intermediate variable

```
int arr0 = array[0];

array[0] = (int) Math.abs(arr0-array[1]);

array[1] = (int) Math.abs(array[1]-array[2]);

array[2] = (int) Math.abs(array[2]-array[3]);

array[3] = (int) Math.abs(array[3]-arr0);
```

something like that. Also, if you want to stop with the four-tuple (0,0,0,0) and not as soon as one entry is zero, change your while header to

```
while ((array[0] != 0) || (array[1] != 0) || (array[2] != 0) || (array[3] != 0))
```

Otherwise, a tuple such as (7,7,6,1) would cause your loop to terminate after the first step, which is not what you want.

Comment: I would also change the condition from && to || . +1

Comment: @c0der that's certainly true, I edited that in, thank you

Answer (score 2):

See comments:

```
int [] array = new int []{7, 3, 6, 1};
int counter = 0;

//the right condition is OR. If one in non zero - continue the computation
//&& will also produce correct results but perform with unneeded checks  
while ((array[0] != 0) || (array[1] != 0) || (array[2] != 0) || (array[3] != 0)){

    int arr0 = array[0]; //keep and use to calc array[3]

    array[0] = Math.abs(array[0]-array[1]);
    array[1] = Math.abs(array[1]-array[2]);
    array[2] = Math.abs(array[2]-array[3]);
    array[3] = Math.abs(array[3]-arr0);

    counter++;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)+ " Counter="+ counter);
```

Comment: Thank you! Initializing a new integer seemed so obvious. Beginners such as myself make mistakes like these a lot lol

Comment: That is fine. That is how you learn. I think @Banana answer should be accepted, as he was the first one to post the correct answer.